# How to count distinct values in a varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to count a column which has different values inside of it.

The column I am interested in is **routes**, but the issue I am running into is that the datatype for this column is a VARCHAR.

I'm wondering if there is a way to count distinct occurrences that appear in this column.

```
+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+
| stop_id | on_street               | cross_street                | routes                                        | boardings | alightings | month_beginning | day_type | location                    |
+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+
|       1 | JACKSON                 | AUSTIN                      | 126                                           |       183 |        150 | 2012-10-01      | Weekday  | (41.87632184, -87.77410482) |
|      48 | HARRISON                | WOOD                        | 126                                           |         1 |          2 | 2012-10-01      | Weekday  | (41.87405900, -87.67133400) |
|      50 | ASHLAND                 | CONGRESS                    | 9,126                                         |        15 |         27 | 2012-10-01      | Weekday  | (41.87508698, -87.66643194) |
|      52 | JACKSON                 | 1900 W.(MALCOLM X COLL.)    | 126                                           |        83 |        229 | 2012-10-01      | Weekday  | (41.87743988, -87.67402389) |
|      69 | JACKSON                 | FINANCIAL PLACE             | 1,7,X28,126,129,130,132,151                   |       118 |        185 | 2012-10-01      | Weekday  | (41.87808100, -87.63286800) |
|      71 | JACKSON                 | STATE                       | 1,7,X28,126,129,130                           |       201 |        750 | 2012-10-01      | Weekday  | (41.87814100, -87.62789900) |
|      73 | MICHIGAN                | betw. VAN BUREN & CONGRES   | 1,3,4,7,J14,26,X28,126,129,132,143,147,148    |       966 |        922 | 2012-10-01      | Weekday  | (41.87627100, -87.62439600) |
|      75 | MICHIGAN                | VAN BUREN                   | 1,7,X28,126,129                               |       290 |         91 | 2012-10-01      | Weekday  | (41.87669000, -87.62416000) |
```

Comment: `WHERE` goes after `FROM` and before `GROUP BY`.  The rest of the query should be fine.

Comment: You need to normalize your tables. Storing comma separated value is not good. You should have a stop_to_routes table with one to many relationship

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya That's great advice and I appreciate it. However, my follow-up question would be...is it possible to do that when you were given a CSV to create the database?

Comment: Yes, if you are using PHP for your application code, look at `explode` function.

Comment: I'm actually using python for this particular application.

Comment: @JoelCarter I am sure python will have equivalents. Check [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) functions.